# Unable to access the query variables in the template

Tags: url-rewriting

I added a custom endpoint `'product'` in the pages.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_endpoints');
function add_endpoints() {
   add_rewrite( 'product', EP_PAGES );
}
```

I added a shortcode called `'dashboard' shortcode in a page.

```
add_shortcode( 'ims-dashboard', 'dashboard' );
public function dashboard() {
   global $wp_query;

   return ims_get_template_html( 'admin-panel/admin-panel.php' );

}
```

When i access the page https://localhost/dashboard-2/product, it is rendered correctly.

But whenever I access the page https://localhost/dashboard-2/product/add, the

> Oops! That page can’t be found.

is occurred.

I want to load the different page when the url is https://localhost/dashboard-2/product/add.

Comment: Do you have a post type of `product` on your site? If so, change the name of the endpoint - e.g. to `product2` .. And there's a typo in the question - it's `add_rewrite_endpoint()`, not `add_rewrite()`.

Comment: It seems I did. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: So I suppose you've also flushed the rewrite rules?

Comment: I had woocommerce plugin installed. It has product post type. I deactivated the WooCommerce plugin and it no works. Guess, I need to rename the endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I missed your comment edit. So make certain that the endpoint name does not clash with a post type *slug* - e.g. the `product` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have WooCommerce installed. It has registered the product post type which was conflicting with it.

I renamed to endpoint and it works.